# Using PHP to fetch content from a DOM node but not from its children

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

Is it possible to use PHP's DOMXPath (or a similar alternative) to extract the value `bar` but not the value `foo` from the following structure?

```
<div>
    <p><span>foo</span>bar</p>
</div>
```

All of my attempts so far have returned content from the node's descendants as well as from the node itself, which is not what I want in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is just to look for text nodes that are direct children of `p`:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div/p/text()');
```

You may want a different selector in place of `//div/`, but the key bit is `p/text()`. `/` means "direct child nodes only" and `text()` means "text nodes only". So together they mean "direct children that are text nodes".

Answer (score 1):

Credit should go to @lonesomeday since I updated my answer with his method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div><p><span>foo</span>bar</p></div>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div/p/text()');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . '<br>';
}
```

[Read this tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html#matching-all-descendants) for more help with syntax.